# Fix a marker on google map and then move it again

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios

[image]

[image]

I do not know what the proper question would be therefore my Title may not be properly descriptive, apology for that. I want to achieve the functionality like the picture above. Now in my project I have two **textField**, **starttxtField** and **destTextField**. When I select **starttxtField** and **imageView** containing an image appear in the middle of the map like a pin and I can get the **lat**, **lan** of that respective place, no problem with that. I can do similar with **destTextField** as well. Now how can I do similar like the picture above, When I select the **starttxtField** an **imageView** appear like a pin and I can select a place, when I select the **destTextField** the previous pin will remain in the map and will move along as I move the map. When I select the **destTextField** an **imageView** will appear as a pin, but when I select the **starttxtField** the previous pin will stick in the selected place and can be moved along while map is moved. Hope I could make my question clear.

My **imageView** containing a marker is like this:

```
let startMarkerView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "startMarker1")
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return imageView
}()
```

constraints of the image view is :

```
 // need x, y, width & height constraints
 startMarkerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
 startMarkerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
 startMarkerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
 startMarkerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

First I add the **startMarkerView** subView and hide it, when **textField** began editing it become visible, no problem with that. My google map function is :

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {

 let startCoordinate = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: startMarkerView.center)
 print("myLatitude " + "\(startCoordinate.latitude)" + " myLongitude " + "\(startCoordinate.longitude)")

  let endCoordinate = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: endMarkerView.center)
  print("myLatitude " + "\(endCoordinate.latitude)" + " myLongitude " + "\(endCoordinate.longitude)")


}
```